# How to add tooltip to Map Annotation in order to show the location name on the Map using MapKit (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to figure out how I can display the title/name of a MapAnnotation when I hover over the Annotation/Marker or when I simply tap on the annotation/Marker. Is there a simple way to do this?

I tried using .help(), but it doesn't display anything on the map...

Here is the relevant code...

```
  Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: viewModel.locations){ location in
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate) {

    Image(systemName: "mappin.circle")
    .help("\(location.name)")

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add a tooltip to a map annotation. You make your own custom view. You can display it however you want, and show and hide child views as desired. As an example:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct MapAnnotationsView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.889499, longitude: -77.035230), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    
    let placeArray: [Place] = [Place(title: "Washington Monument", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.889499, longitude: -77.035230))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray) { annotation in
            // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
                // This is your custom view
                AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnnotationView: View {
    
    let placeName: String
    @State private var showPlaceName = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(placeName)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    // Prevents truncation of the Text
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                    // Displays and hides the place name
                    .opacity(showPlaceName ? 1 : 0)
            
            // You can use whatever you want here. This is a custom annotation marker
            // made to look like a standard annotation marker.
            Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -5)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                showPlaceName.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct Place: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *.help()* will work as long as you use it with a button.
This is a quick paste from a current project I’ve got.

**Note:**
*This works with the Mac version and I have not tested anywhere else*

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct SwiftUIMapViewTest: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 29.548460, longitude: -98.481556),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
    @Binding var selectedListing: Place?
    @Binding var results: [Place]
    @State var image: String = "mappin"
                
         var body: some View {
                    
             Map(
                 coordinateRegion: $region,
                 annotationItems: results,
                 annotationContent: {
                     listing in
                     MapAnnotation(coordinate: listing.coordinate,
                            content: {Button(action: {
                                        self.selectedListing = listing as Place?
                                  },
                                  label: {
                                      VStack{
                                          Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                                               .foregroundColor(.red)
                                               .contentShape(Circle())
                                        }
                                    }).help("\(listing.company) \n\(listing.street) \n\(String(listing.zipCode))")
                                }
                            )})
                }
}

struct SwiftUIMapViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var modelData = [ModelData().places]
    static var modelPlace = ModelData().places
    static var previews: some View {

    SwiftUIMapViewTest(
        selectedListing: .constant(modelPlace[0]),
                results: .constant(modelData[0])
                    )
                }
            }
```

Although not very pritty, this is the result.

[image: a view of the mouseover]

Hope this helps someone.