# Creating mapmarker in Swiftui interface?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to create a mapmarker on my screen via mapkit for 1 week. These mapmarkers come from the api I have as latitude and longitude. However, I learned swift 1 month ago and I'm having a hard time. Is there someone to help me? Code and screenshot attached.

Obviously what I want is to know where to write the codes and to know which codes to use. (My interface is swift, there is usually a storyboard interface on the internet)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct depremHaritasi: View {

    @State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = []

    @State var coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
          center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142),
          span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

        var body: some View {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
            Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
                self.quakes = quakes
            }
        }
}
}


struct depremHaritasi_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       depremHaritasi()
   }
}
```

[Earthquake Map Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMspb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add tooltip to Map Annotation in order to show the location name on the Map using MapKit (SwiftUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499366/how-to-add-tooltip-to-map-annotation-in-order-to-show-the-location-name-on-the-m)

Comment: I did the same in the link you sent, but this time I get the error "Cannot find 'earthquakeMap' in scope" in the contentview.swift file. // name of the map screen depremHaritasi

Comment: You have to keep names consistent in your own code. You obviously didn't change a name in the example when you copied and pasted it.